# Get zaxis range from Plotly 3D

Tags: plotly

I use JavaScript to produce 3D scatter plots in Plotly.  Initially, I do not specify the axis ranges.  However, I want to let the user set the zaxis range manually after the plots are initially drawn. In that user interaction, I want to populate the range values with existing (as-drawn) settings.  How do I extract the zaxis range from an existing Plotly scatter3d chart?

```js
Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv', function(err, rows) {
  function unpack(rows, key) {
    return rows.map(function(row) {
      return row[key];
    });
  }

  
  var data = [];
  
  for (i = 0; i < 24; i += 1) {

    var x_row = [], 
        y_row = [],
        z_row = unpack(rows, i);
    
    for (var j = 0; j < z_row.length; j++) {
       x_row.push(i);
       y_row.push(j);
    }
    
    data.push({
      x: x_row,
      y: y_row,
      z: z_row,
      mode: 'lines',
      line: {
        color: '#FF00FF'
      },
      type: 'scatter3d'
    });
  }
  
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

  document.getElementById('cmax').innerHTML = 'Max: ' + data[0].cmax;
  document.getElementById('cmin').innerHTML = 'Min: ' + data[0].cmin;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='cmax'></div>
<div id='cmin'></div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment it's a scatter3D plot, the solution below works for 3D surface plots. For scatter3D plot's [Plotly](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/91c0b8d73f3af7fe160ec483807737413bfc66d8/src/plots/gl3d/scene.js) calculates the axis ranges based on the min and max value of the input array.

```
sceneBounds[0][i] = Math.min(sceneBounds[0][i], objBounds[0][i] / dataScale[i]);
```

From there you could set your ranges manually to the min/max values (+ some extra space) or leave the ranges empty and populate your default values with the max resp. min values.

---

Plotly sets the the max and min value to `cmax` resp. `cmin` of the data object which is passed to the `newPlot` function.

```js
Plotly.d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv', function(err, rows) {
  function unpack(rows, key) {
    return rows.map(function(row) {
      return row[key];
    });
  }

  var z_data = []
  for (i = 0; i < 24; i += 1) {
    z_data.push(unpack(rows, i));
  }

  var data = [{
    z: z_data,
    type: 'surface'
  }];
  
  Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  
  document.getElementById('cmax').innerHTML = 'Max: ' + data[0].cmax;
  document.getElementById('cmin').innerHTML = 'Min: ' + data[0].cmin;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='cmax'></div>
<div id='cmin'></div>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It appears I left out a crucial piece of information.  The chart type is scatter3d.  In that case, cmax and cmin do not get added to data[0].  I will update my question with an example similar to yours.

Comment: @JimNorman: see updated answer, I hope the answer is as easy as I think.